# How to turn str into class

Tags: python, discord.py

So I want to save my message details in the .ini file so my bot can reuse it even after I reboot it. The problem is that to save it, I need to convert <class 'discord.message.Message'> into a string and I don't know how to convert it back to what it was before.

```
msg = config["INFO"]["rods_message"]

    if msg == 'null':
        msg = await client.get_channel(int(config["INFO"]["discordspamChannelID"])).send(
            f"Blaze rod price: **{matches}**")
    else:
        await msg.edit(content=f"Blaze rod price: **{matches}**")
        config["INFO"]["rods_message"] = str(msg)
        with open('info.ini', 'w') as cfg:  # saves data gathered above to info.ini
            #                               (also creates info.ini if it doesnt exist somehow)
            config.write(cfg)
```

After reboot, I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'edit'

Comment: Have you considered keeping the relevant data in a class then using *pickle* to save and recover it?

Comment: No, I don't even know what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the message content, you want to have to save the message id (using `msg.id`) inside your .ini file. This way, you're able to fetch the message object each time your bot starts up.

So instead of `config["INFO"]["rods_message"] = str(msg)`, you will want: `config["INFO"]["rods_message"] = msg.id`. This way, you are saving the message id (an integer) instead of the message content (a string) in your file.

Now, in order to convert this integer into a `Message` object, you will have to use a few methods of `discord.Client`.

First, ensure that the data you are reading from the file is an integer by replacing `msg = config["INFO"]["rods_message"]` with `msg_id = int(config["INFO"]["rods_message"])`

Next, get the channel that this message is in. You can do this by putting this line of code underneath the line we just edited:
`channel = client.get_channel(int(config["INFO"]["discordspamChannelID"]))`

Finally, this is where you convert your message id (an integer) into a message (a `Message` object). Underneath the previous line, add this code: `msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)`

And that's it! You've now retrieved the original message object by using the ID of the message rather than its content.